# Shiny app stops due to error. How to manage such errors

Tags: r, error-handling, shiny

I have a shiny app where I call a function from a different package. So when I call this function if the values are not in a certain range that function throws an error and the app stops.
Eg function :

`data <- callFunction(cost,input1,input2)`

So when the `callFunction` throws an error it stops the app. I dont want the app to stop and just throw a message on the app saying your inputs are incorrect please modify it. How can I do this in a shiny app.Thank you.

Comment: You could reject the inputs using validate, [docs](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html)

Answer (score 0):

For error handling, R implements `tryCatch`

```
Test <- list(5,4,"foo","bar")
res <-  sapply(Test,function(el)
  {
  tryCatch({
#Expression that might throw an error
  el + 5
}, warning = function(w) {
  print("Warning. Minor Problems!") #warning handling
}, error = function(e) {
  print("Error!. Major Problems!") #error handling
}, finally = {
#possible clean-up code.
})})

res
[1] "10"       "9"   "Error!. Major Problems!" "Error!. Major Problems!
```